# Scanning from a file in C

Tags: c, file, eof

I am trying to scan a string from a file using the code below. But my program prints weird characters. Any ideas how to stop this and how to keep spaces between words when printing the string?

here are the contents of the file (test.txt)
[image: (test.txt)]

Here is the output of my program:

[image: output]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
   char word[80];
   int length;
   int freq;
} sent;

int main()
{
   sent a[50];
   int v,status;
   int i=0,cnt=0;
   char*y;

   FILE*p;
   p=fopen("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\test.txt","r");
   status=fscanf(p,"%s",a[i].word);
   while(status !=EOF){
      i++;
      status=fscanf(p,"%s",a[i].word);
   }
   for(i=0;i<50;i++)
   {
      char *y=strtok(a[i].word,"!@#$%&*?.");

      while(y!=NULL)
      {
         printf("%s",y);
         y=strtok(NULL,"!@#$%&*?.");

      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Please post the contents of test.txt. My guess is that you don't have 50 words in the file.

Comment: fscanf(p,"%s",a[i].word); can end in a buffer overflow, use fscanf(p,"%79s",a[i].word); or fgets(). and check for errors after fopen()

Answer (score 2):

As people have commented, you are likely not having 50 words in the file you read, but your loop tries to loop over 50 anyway...., so this line

```
for(i=0;i<50;i++)
```

should be modified to

```
int w;
for(w=0;w<i;w++)
```

and you should replace the use of `i` with `w` inside the loop (or maybe you intended to use the variable `cnt` inside the while loop, since that is currently unused in your code).

And you need protection for buffer overruns that would happen if your file would have more than 50 words etc, but that is beyond the scope of this answer.

**Update** to answer your comment:

To have space between the words, you simply just add them to the output, like

```
printf("%s ",y);
```

Your scanf will however terminate the string scan at any space, so space (hex 20), newline (\n), tab (\t) or return (\r) will all be terminating characters for your strings -- If you want to preserve and output the same, you simply just scan for those as well, like

```
  char theString[50];
  char theSpace;
  int matched = scanf("%s%c",theString, theSpace);
```

and if matched == 2 then you have scanned both a string and the space that terminated the scan, and you can print it like

```
  printf("%s%c",theModifiedString,theSpace);
```

Comment: so `i` here refers to the number of words not the numbers of characters in the file..... i counted the words in the file and changed the loop according to the number ...it worked but there are no spaces between the words how can i keep the spaces between them ??....thank you for the answer it helped

Comment: if i used `printf("%s  ",y);` it will not work because i have special characters in between the characters of the word itself ,so there will be spaces between the characters in the word.

Comment: Im not sure I understand your question -- you comment asked for how to print the spaces, and there is a long explanation on how to do that -- maybe you are printing the spaces inside the while loop, where you clearly should do it outside after printing each word?

Answer (score 0):

It's just string manipulation. I debugged and modified your program a little so that there is text output instead of junk. You might need to modify it some more, but it does print the contents of the file now. The reason you got junk character is that the loop doesn't know when to stop when the string is not terminated, so you get memory contents from something else. The recommended way is `fgets` to read a file and whitespace is preserved.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char *word;
    int length;
    int freq;
} sent;

int words(const char *sentence) {
    int count, i, len;
    char lastC;
    len = strlen(sentence);
    if (len > 0) {
        lastC = sentence[0];
    }
    for (i = 0; i <= len; i++) {
        if (sentence[i] == ' ' && lastC != ' ') {
            count++;
        }
        lastC = sentence[i];
    }
    if (count > 0 && sentence[i] != ' ') {
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}

int main() {
    sent a[50];
    int v, status;
    int i = 0, cnt = 0;
    FILE *p;
    p = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    char buf[100], title[100];
    fgets(buf, sizeof buf, p);
    int j = words(buf);
    char *yy;
    yy = strtok(buf, "!@#$&*?%.");

    while (yy != NULL) {
        a[i].word = yy;
        yy = strtok(NULL, "!@#$&*?%.");
        i++;
    }

    for (int k = 0; k<i; k++) {
        printf("%s", a[k].word);
    }
}
```

The program tokenizes the buffer and keeps the whitespace. I changed the way you read the file to `fgets`.

**data.txt**

> On a scale from one to ten what$ is your favorite color of the alphabet

**output**

On a scale from one to ten what is your favorite color of the alphabet

Comment: Please describe what modifications you had to make to the OP's code so it works for you.

Comment: @RSahu I added improved code and more description. I hope you approve or comment again.

Comment: @Programmer400 -- you make no mentions on why your code is better or why his code failed....

Comment: @Soren I updated with more description. My strategy was to read the entire file as a string and then tokenize it, plus using a `char *` for the word instead of a `char[]`. If it's not perfect we can "pull request" it....

Comment: That's lot of change to the OP's code when the only thing he needs to change to fix his problem is change the last loop.